# What is the best way to build a network of WP sites that share the same membership area?

Tags: multisite, membership

I have a potential client who wants to build a network of 20 or 30 sites that all use the same membership area. In addition, an account set up on one site will get the user into any of the sites in the network.

What is the best way to do this? WP mutli site? How best to handle the membership issues?

Many thanks,

Cynthia

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a multisite network that will cover your 20-30 sites. We run a similar type application where we have a site for each school on our network. From there, you could use the following plugin to automatically add users to your blogs.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management/